# A question about parallel diode configuration

Tags: diodes

In a textbook when mentioning a setup to measure a simple 10uA ammeter's internal resistance, they recommend to connect two diodes with opposite orientation in parallel with the (ammeter). The setup is to measure the internal resistance of the ammeter.

They claim these diodes will conduct around 0.6V, and will protect the meter movement during overdrive.

This is what I understand from what they mean, so I draw it in LTspice (please left-click to enlarge the image):

[image]

As you see current keeps increasing with the input voltage. But this doesn't make sense to me. (L1 and R1 represent the analog ammeter)

Am I understanding and drawing something wrong here? How would diodes protect the ammeter.

**Edit:**

Here is the circuit response with a realistic power supply:

[image]

It dramatically limits the current but still above 10uA. I guess 200uA is not a problem since the power dissipation is around 0.2mW?

Comment: The diodes will make sure that no more than the drop over them will be across the meter. Simulating this with an ideal voltage source makes no sense, if at all to see something remotely resembling reality, try it with some current source.

Comment: So the configuration I draw is right? But they use power supply in setup not a current source. I dont get that

Comment: You are using an ideal voltage source to simulate measuring a current, how can that be right?

Comment: Presumably your graph is measuring the 1.8mA through the resistor and inductor, and not the eleventy zillion amps going through the diode.

Comment: The meter movement has very thin wire. If you put a lot of current through it, caused by, say, a potential difference of 1 V, it will melt. The diodes will limit the P.D. which can appear over the meter movement.

Comment: Please see my edit. I think ideal source is problem as you mentioned . But In real life when using a bench power supply would you add a series resistance or the power supply's Thevenin resistance is enough to rescue and no need for a series resistor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are plotting the current through R1 the 5 k resistor right ?

And you use an **ideal** voltage source for testing.

In your current circuit, your "Ampere meter" will **NOT** be protected because the two diodes can **conduct all they want** but the current is delivered by **an ideal voltage source**.

That current source will simply make 10000 Amps flow if that is what it takes to make 9 V. Then 9999.998 Amps will flow through the diode and 2 mA will flow through your 5 k meter.

What you need to do is add some resistance in series with the voltage source. Start with 100 ohms and see how that goes.

Comment: Yes I plot through 5k. Only if I add 1MegaOhm series to the ideal power supply I can limit ammeter's current to 10uA. But then I dont need the diodes. Whats the point? I dont get the use of those diodes here

Comment: Read my answer again and try it **not with 1 M ohm but with 100 ohms**, now sweep V1 from -10 V to + 10 V then plot the current through the 5 k resistor. Just "trying" with random values like 1 Mohm does not bring you anything as you take the whole setup to the other extreme. The best case would be to use a current limited voltage source and limit the current to 1 A. But that is for advanced users. Just add the 100 ohm in series with V1 and see what happens. Then remove the diodes and simulate again. Now explain the difference.

Comment: see my edit, i followed your suggestions. It dramatically limits the current to around max 200uA but still above 10uA. I guess 200uA is not a problem since the power dissipation is around 0.2mW right?

Comment: and one more thing: in real life when using a bench power supply would you add a series resistance or the power supply's Thevenin resistance is enough to rescue and no need for a series resistor?

Comment: The current through the meter will be limited to roughly 0.7 V / 5 k ohm = 140 uA. In your case the drop across the diodes is more like 1 V so you get 200 uA. Indeed, usually that is low enough to prevent damage to the meter. In practice there will always be a series resistor with the protected meter. To make a voltage meter use a high value resistor. For a current meter, you measure the voltage across a current shunt resistor which will have a low value. The power supply's Thevenin resistor cannot be relied upon because power supplies have a low output resistance.

Comment: BTW, talking about a "Power supply's Thevenin resistor" is confusing. Just call it "output impedance", it is the small signal output resistance dV/dI . Since power supplies have active feedback, this value can be very low, like less than 50 milli ohms. Only when a power supply hits its current limit, it will source current and the output impedance will go up in value.